# Airflow run specifying incorrect -sd or -SUBDIRECTORY

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow process running every day with many DAGS. Today, all of a sudden, none of the DAGS can be run because when Airflow calls `airflow run` it misspecifies the -sd directory to find the DAG.

Here's the example:

```
[2018-09-26 15:18:10,406] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run daily_execution dag1 2018-09-26T13:17:50.511269 --job_id 1 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/newfoldernewfolder/dags/all_dags.py']
```

As you can see, right after `-sd`, the the subdirectory repeates newfolder twice when it should only state `DAGS_FOLDER/newfolder/dags/all_dags.py`.

I tried running the DAG with the same files that were running two days ago (when everything was correct) but I get the same error. I'm guessing that something has changed in Airflow configuration but I'm not aware of any changes in `airflow.cfg`. I've been only managing the UI and `airflow run` gets called automatically once I turn the DAG on.

Anybody has an idea where `airflow run` might get this directory and how I can update this?

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using?